# "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar" when trying to get datediff

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math, overflow, datediff

```
Level1  Level2      createdate        CCcreatedate      datedifference

23    |   3   |  10/24/2014 17:07   | 10/24/2014 17:07  
24    |   3   |  10/24/2014 23:48   | 10/25/2014 17:07  
25    |   3   |  10/25/2014 9:57    | 10/26/2014 17:07  
26    |   1   |  10/26/2014 17:49   | 10/27/2014 17:07  
27    |   1   |  10/16/2014 12:53   | 10/28/2014 17:07  
28    |   1   |  10/16/2014 12:32   | 10/29/2014 17:07  
29    |   2   |  10/16/2014 13:58   | 10/30/2014 17:07  
30    |   2   |  10/16/2014 16:40   | 10/31/2014 17:07  
31    |   2   |  10/16/2014 20:28   | 11/1/2014 17:07   
32    |   2   |  10/15/2014 17:09   | 11/2/2014 17:07
```

I have a table with 5 columns, 2 of which are dates. One declared as `nvarchar`(`createdate`) and the other as `datetime` (`CCcreatedate`)
I am trying to get the difference between the 2 dates to show up on a 3rd column (`datedifference`) which is also `nvarchar`. Getting an error stating

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

when i use the query below.

```
update table
set datedifference = 
datediff(minute,CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST([createdate] as datetime)),CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST([CE_activity_create_Date]as datetime)))
```

I am trying find the difference between the 2 dates so I can later get the distinct (Level 2) with minimum datedifference

Comment: How big is the `varchar` column? And why are you using a `varchar` column to store a numeric value?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Thanks guys. It was an issue with the datatype.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to make your datedifference column larger.  I just got the same error you did when I ran the following code:

```
declare @T nvarchar(3)
Select @T = DateDiff(minute, '10/15/2014 17:09','11/2/2014 17:07')
```

The difference, in minutes is 25,918.  If your nvarchar column is too small, you get the error.  I would encourage you to change the data type of your datedifference column to int instead of nvarchar.

You can use this code to see how large (or small) or column is:

```
Select max_length 
from   sys.columns 
where  name = 'datedifference' 
       and object_id = object_id('YourTableNameHere')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the update query should be:

```
update table
set datedifference = 
datediff(minute,CONVERT(datetime,[createdate] ),CONVERT(datetime,[CE_activity_create_Date]))
```

Be aware that dates more than about ten weeks apart would require 6 digits to store *just* the integer part.  It would be *much* better to store the result as a numeric column if possible.